# MediaFoundation gives four cameras into one single frame

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to get the depth camera of the HoloLens 2 using MediaFoundation. This thread is then related to UWP and MediaFoundation.

With this initialization C# code (there is some C++ code of mine to handle the MediaFoundation pipeline), I am able to get the [following captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvtE9.png) which I modified using gimp to emphasis low values (i.e., the image pasted is brighter).

```
/// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously create a Hand Detector with the first depth camera found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The ID of the device to look for if needed. If NULL, a device with "depth" capabilities will be randomly choose.</param>
    /// <returns>The asynchronous task</returns>
    public static async Task<HandDetector> CreateAsync(String id=null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Initialize the hand detector");

        //Search for the correct media frame source
        MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedFrameSourceGroup = null;
        MediaFrameSourceInfo  selectedFrameSourceInfo  = null;

        IReadOnlyList<MediaFrameSourceGroup> allFrameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Found {allFrameSourceGroups.Count} frame sources...");

        foreach (MediaFrameSourceGroup group in allFrameSourceGroups)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Group: {group.DisplayName}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Found {group.SourceInfos.Count} source infos...");
            foreach(MediaFrameSourceInfo info in group.SourceInfos)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine($"{info.SourceKind} : {info.MediaStreamType} -> {info.DeviceInformation.EnclosureLocation.Panel}");
                //If an ID is given
                if ((id == null || info.DeviceInformation.Id == id) && (info.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoPreview || info.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord))
                {
                    //Check the depth capabilities
                    if (info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Depth)
                    {                            
                        selectedFrameSourceGroup = group;
                        selectedFrameSourceInfo = info;

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Found Device : {info.DeviceInformation.Name}:{info.DeviceInformation.Id}");
                    }
                }

                if (selectedFrameSourceGroup != null)
                    break;
            }
            if(selectedFrameSourceGroup != null)
                break;
        }

        if (selectedFrameSourceGroup == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No frame source available found");
            return null;
        }

        HandDetector HandDetector = new HandDetector(selectedFrameSourceGroup, selectedFrameSourceInfo);
        return HandDetector;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates asynchronously the Media Capture which will process the depth stream images
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clbk">The Callback object to call when the hand detection status changes.</param>
    /// <returns>The asynchronous task</returns>
    public async Task InitializeAsync(IHDMediaSinkClbk clbk)
    {
        //Create the media capture
        Debug.WriteLine("Creating a media capture...");
        m_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await m_mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
        {
            SourceGroup             = m_mediaGroup,
            SharingMode             = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly,
            MemoryPreference        = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Auto,   //For the Hololens, MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.CPU does not work
            StreamingCaptureMode    = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
        });

        //Find a correct video profile with the best capabilities (resolution)
        Debug.WriteLine("Search a video profile...");
        VideoEncodingProperties videoProfile = null;
        var mediaProperties = m_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
        UInt32 maxHeight = 0;

        foreach (var mediaProp in mediaProperties)
        {
            VideoEncodingProperties videoProp = mediaProp as VideoEncodingProperties;
            Debug.WriteLine($"VideoProp : {videoProp.Type}:{videoProp.Subtype} {videoProp.Width}x{videoProp.Height}");
            if(videoProp.Subtype == "ARGB32" || videoProp.Subtype == "L8" || videoProp.Subtype == "D16" || videoProp.Subtype == "D8" || videoProp.Subtype == "L16" || videoProp.Subtype == "RGB24")
            { 
                if(maxHeight < videoProp.Height)
                { 
                    videoProfile = videoProp;
                    maxHeight = videoProp.Height;
                }
            }
        }

        if (videoProfile == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No video profile found...");
            await Task.FromResult<Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction>(null);
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Starting to preview {m_mediaInfo.DeviceInformation.Name} : {m_mediaInfo.DeviceInformation.Id} at {videoProfile.Width}x{videoProfile.Height}: {videoProfile.Subtype}");

            //Create the video encoding
            MediaEncodingProfile profile = new MediaEncodingProfile();
            profile.Video = videoProfile;
            profile.Audio = null;

            //Create and start preview in the MediaSink
            Debug.WriteLine(m_mediaInfo.DeviceInformation.Name);
            m_mediaSink = new HDMediaSinkProxy();
            IMediaExtension ext = await m_mediaSink.InitializeAsync(clbk, profile.Video);
            await m_mediaCapture.StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync(profile, ext);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("End of Create media capture async");
    }
```

As you guys can see, I am capturing FOUR modes for a given camera frame (one depth, one IR camera, and two unknown cameras), when I only want the depth values in that frame. With the HoloLens1, I was able to get only the depth camera with this exact same code, without having all the remaining images that will, unlikely, be hard to parse (because I did not find any metadata helping me to crop the image…). I want to avoid hardcoding numeric values if possible.

Do you guys know how to automaticaly extract the top image?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the two choices you have are to filter your video capture devices on either their name or their media properties. You seem to be sort of doing that already. Is the depth image a different sub video format to the others? Why not iterate over your capture devices and select the one that has the matching sub video format?

Comment: In fact I already iterated over ALL my cameras in CreateAsync (I checked manually that I had no other MediaFrameSourceInfo than the one I showed you which has depth capacities).

Comment: Yes but that's the point. When iterating over the cameras can't you check the media types it supports and identify your depth camera that way?

Comment: That is what "if (info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Depth)" does in CreateAsync

Comment: So the problem is that info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Depth now matches for all your video capture devices whereas with the Hololens1 it only matched the depth camera? A quick check of the docs and ii looks like you can set what capabilities you want when you intiailise the MediaCapture object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-profiles.

Comment: The issue now is that for ONE capture device, I do have the frame that I pasted (this is a complete frame which looks like it embeds 4 different frames)

Comment: Ok, so the issue is a single video capture device is seemingly giving you 4 images combined together in a single sample? If that's the case it'd be worth editing your question and subject to make it clearer. It's taken me this far to decipher what the problem is.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the inconvenience (and yeah that is the issue)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can [Set the preferred format for the frame source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#set-the-preferred-format-for-the-frame-source)

```
var colorFrameSource = mediaCapture.FrameSources[colorSourceInfo.Id];
var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.Where(format =>
{
    return format.VideoFormat.Width >= 1080
    && format.Subtype == MediaEncodingSubtypes.Argb32;

}).FirstOrDefault();

if (preferredFormat == null)
{
    // Our desired format is not supported
    return;
}

await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);
```

You need to change values to get Depth.

[MediaFrameSource.SetFormatAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframesource.setformatasync)

> This method is an alternative to MediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync, but unlike SetEncodingPropertiesAsync, this method can be used with any stream, not just the color camera preview, record, and photo capture streams.